# Ruby GtkTreeView reorder

Tags: ruby, sorting, gtk, drag-and-drop, gtktreeview

I have to use a Gtk DnD sorted treeview.
There is no problem with the DnD but I do not understand how to sort nodes.
I am trying to use `Gtk::TreeStore.reorder(parent, new_order)` but I do not understand
what is wrong.

Extract form my code :

```
@store = Gtk::TreeStore.new(String, String, String, String)
@tree  =Gtk::TreeView.new(@store)
@tree.set_headers_visible(false)

column   = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new
renderer = Gtk::CellRendererPixbuf.new
column.pack_start(renderer, false)
column.add_attribute(renderer, 'stock_id', 2)

renderer = Gtk::CellRendererText.new
column.pack_start(renderer, true)
column.add_attribute(renderer, "text", 1)

@tree.append_column(column)

@tree.enable_tree_lines=true

@tree.selection.mode = Gtk::SELECTION_SINGLE

def fct_Treeview_orderIter(treeviewIter, store)

    arrResult=Array.new
    arrTmp=Array.new

    hNodes=Hash.new
    hResult=Hash.new

    nbiter=treeviewIter.n_children

    p "nb children=#{nbiter}"
    (0..nbiter-1).each do |index|
        child_iter=treeviewIter.nth_child(index)
        hNodes[index]=child_iter[1]
        #fct_Treeview_orderIter(child_iter, store)
    end

    arrTmp=hNodes.to_a.sort do |a, b|
        a[1] <=> b[1]
    end

    arrResult=arrTmp.collect { |entry| [entry[0].to_i] }.flatten

    store.reorder(treeviewIter, arrResult)
end
```

I have the same error message as [this example for a liststore...](http://www.ruby-forum.com/attachment/3177/es.rb)

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Hi, welcome.  What is the error you are getting, please?

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in ruby-gnome2 (http://sourceforge.net/p/ruby-gnome2/bugs/179/).

- apt-get install ruby-gnome2-dev ;
- Download ruby-gnome2 from master source branch ;
- Compile and install.

Have fun !